# Android Firebase database limitToLast(1) weird behaviour

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a very simple code:

```
//   get users poll date, and set in relevant text view
Query query = gameRef.child("users_loto").child("zaalkIb4W0V7MGbekLhqjP34IQi1").orderByChild("pollRank").limitToLast(1);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                nDate = Long.parseLong(ds.child("pollRank").getValue().toString().substring(0, 14));
                user_result.setText(String.valueOf(nDate));
            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

I ordered it by pollRank - it is the same number as the child name.

It seems to return the last value of the relevant node:
[image]

But instead, it always returns the one before :
[image]

A very weird behavior...
Any thoughts about why it happens?

Comment: Your query is ordering the children by pollRank, right?  Not the name of the child?  Why do you expect a different result?  Please edit the question to explain.

Comment: The pollRank and the child name(number)is the same number

Comment: Could you show that data so we can see for ourselves?

Comment: @DougStevenson, attached

Comment: And what's the data in the child that you get other than the one you expect?  We need to be able to see everything in use here.

Comment: @DougStevenson, attached

Comment: Can you replace the screenshots of JSON with the actual JSON as text of the last few nodes?  That also allows you to get rid of most properties that are not relevant. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen , done

Comment: Thanks. I can't reproduce it with the JavaScript client here: https://jsbin.com/wecahoq/edit?js,console, and the clients usually work completly the same. Did you declare an index on `pollRank` in your security rules with `"zaalkIb4W0V7MGbekLhqjP34IQi1": { ".indexOn": "pollRank" }`?

Comment: try with YourDocumentRef.keepSynced(true);

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, did it like this:
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "rules": {
    "users_loto": {
      ".indexOn": ["pollRank"]
    }
    }}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tnx for @ShehanWisumperuma!

gameRef.keepSynced(true) was the correct answer to my issue!!!

Tnx for all of you who tried to help me!